# Scraping with Cheerio - Cannot Extract Text

Tags: javascript, dom, cheerio

I am getting an array of empty strings while scraping HTML elements using Cheerio.

I am providing Cheerio with DOM Paths to existing HTML elements. These DOM Paths return HTML elements with document.querySelector or jQuery in the browser.

Cheerio is returning an initialize object instead of the expected HTML Element. Chaining the .text() method returns "".

Example:

`let domArr: [ 'html>body>div:nth-child(8).content>div:nth-child(4).spacer>div#siteTable.sitetable.linklisting>div:nth-child(1)#thing_t3_6smcs6.thing.id-t3_6smcs6.odd.link>div:nth-child(5).entry.unvoted>div:nth-child(1).top-matter>p:nth-child(1).title>a.title.may-blank',
  'html>body>div:nth-child(8).content>div:nth-child(4).spacer>div#siteTable.sitetable.linklisting>div:nth-child(3)#thing_t3_6slbyx.thing.id-t3_6slbyx.even.gilded.link>div:nth-child(5).entry.unvoted>div.top-matter>p:nth-child(1).title>a.title.may-blank.outbound' ]`

```
let textArr = [];
domArr.forEach((element) => {
   elementText = $(element).text();
   textArr.push(elementText);
   });


console.log(textArr) // ["", ""]
```

Comment: The HTML or a link to the page would be helpful.

Comment: Data visible in DevTools offers zero guarantee of Cheerio seeing it. DevTools shows elements dynamically added with JS after the page loads.